# What are the security benefits to preventing the storage of a company's public IP on a database?

Tags: ip, whois

For example, the whois database does not contain DJI's public IP (I had to use zenmap traceroute to retrieve it).

Comment: Whois entries needn't ever contain IP addresses.  That's what DNS records are for.   I think this question is based on a false premise.

Comment: No, they needn't but they try to keep their database up to date and only remove information upon request (or some other reason).

Comment: The point is, I wouldn't *ever* expect to find an IP address is a whois record.  That's not what they're there for, and doesn't even really make sense at that level.  Domains don't map to IPs.   So, the question (why would you not see DJI's IP in their whois record) doesn't make sense.

Comment: The public IP is in the DNS record, though, so it *is* made public in a public 'database'

Answer (score 1):

## *What are the security benefits to preventing the storage of a company's public IP on a database?*

None. It is definitely a waste of time and resources trying to prevent other people from knowing the address. I'm basing this off of the assumption that by "company's public IP" you are referring to the IP Address of a company's public website (such as: http://www.mycompany.com).

If someone wanted the IP address of this site, they would 100% of the time be able to get it.

Now, if this is a site in which there exists no DNS record (only accessible via IP Address), there might be a very teeny tiny minute advantage in no public database containing it, but it won't prevent automated sweepers from finding the site and looking for low hanging fruit.

An IP Address is like a street address and a DNS record is like looking on Google Maps for 'Location of ***MyCompany***'s headquarters'. No one will be able to visit if they don't know the street address and the security of the building shouldn't be based on the obscurity of the location.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much none.  Just because someone knows your home address doesn't mean it's any easier for them to break into your house.